# CALayer opacity animation didn't work as I want

Tags: ios, objective-c, caanimation

Look at the code below. It's an easy animation, but when I set the `beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero`, the animation didn't work correctly, otherwise it's ok.

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation 
animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
animation.duration = 2.f;
// animation.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
animation.delegate = self;
[layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"basicAnimation"];
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on "didn't work correctly", but "otherwise it's OK?"

Comment: hi! Cœur, i mean if i remove the code beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero, the animation works correctly. so could you explain it.

Comment: Well, according to the documentation, `AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero` is a "small, non-zero" value that prevents `beginTime` from begin replace with `CACurrentMediaTime()`. So I'm guessing that if you don't set `beginTime` it will be `0.0` and core animation interprets that as "now", vs. setting `beginTime` to some non-zero value which in interpreted to be in absolute media time. But you still haven't explained what you're trying to accomplish or what "didn't work correctly" means.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Cœur. what i want to accomplish is just play the opacity's animation of a layer, as the code showed upside (i want to make the layer hide after 2 seconds, by animation); The "didn't work correctly" means, if i set beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero, the animation seems not work. when the animation finished (the method [animationDidStop:finished:] of delegate has been invoked),  but the layer is still on the screen, it's not hide. so i mean ''it didn't work correctly''. Did i explain clearly?

Comment: If you want the animation to start immediately, set `beginTime` to 0,0 or don't set it at all. I suspect you're setting it to a value that make Core Animation think the animation starts in the past and has already run. Also note that changing to `opacity` to 0.0 won't remove the view or make it hidden, it just makes it invisible.

Comment: yeah, i agress with you,  thanks for your answer.